# How to print integer arrays horizontally?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

This block of code is supposed to sort the numbers in ascending order but it outputs vertically, how can I output them horizontally?

Example Output:

```
    1st array: 1 2 3
    2nd array: 3 4 5
    3rd array: 3 4 6
```

---

```
     int[] i1 = new int[]{3, 2, 1};
        Arrays.sort(i1);
        System.out.print("1st array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i1.length ; index++)
            System.out.print(" " + i1[index]);



        int[] i2 = new int[]{5, 4, 3};
        Arrays.sort(i2);
        System.out.println("2nd array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i2.length ; index++)
            System.out.print(" " + i1[index]);



        int[] i3 = new int[]{6, 3, 4};
        Arrays.sort(i3);
        System.out.print("3nd array : ");
        for(int index=0; index < i3.length ; index++)
          System.out.println("  "  + i3[index]);
```

Comment: `System.out.println` means print and advance one line. use `System.out.print("  "  + i1[index]);`

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i1));`

Comment: I made an edit, now I have 3 arrays. They numbers print horizontally now, but the 2nd and 3rd set of arrays are also on the same horizontal line.

Comment: Now that you know what `System.out.println` does, maybe you want/need to use it to print a line break at a specific place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are using `System.out.println`. It means that it goes to the next line, it works like if you add a line break at the final of the `String`. Change it for `System.out.print` to print all your code in a line.

For example, using **`System.out.println`**:

*Code*

```
System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("World");
```

*Output*

```
Hello
World
```

Now using **`System.out.print`**:

*Code*

```
System.out.print("Hello");
System.out.print("World");
```

*Output*

```
HelloWorld
```

Finally using **`System.out.print`** and **`String` with `\n`**:

*Code*

```
String string = "Hello\nWorld";
System.out.print(string);
```

*Output*

```
Hello
World
```

Look that using `\n` and `System.out.println` have the same behaviour.

Comment: It maybe worked with `\n` in your OS, but some OSes need `\r\n` in order to print the line break. Be careful with that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you very much for the point!

Comment: Please check the link I've posted in ddsu's answer. That will clarify this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Now it is more clear. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use System.out.print instead of System.out.println. The last one appends a line break at the end of the argument. The [line break character(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is(are) the one(s) that make a new line appears on your output.

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder to create a new "row" or System.out.print() to print to the same line

Something like this:

```
 System.out.print("1st array : ");
for(int index=0; index < i1.length ; index++)
  System.out.print("  "  + i1[index]);
```